# Where did the text go?

Tags: ios, swift

Before you down vote, I haven't found anything that looks like this.

So i made a few text files, each is labeled a specific number(corresponding to the day of the month). Each text file has a quote embedded inside. I had it such that when the button is pressed on the view the label that says "Historical" changes to that quote.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func UpdateHistorical(sender: AnyObject) {//step 1
    let a = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: NSDate())
    HistoricalLabel.text = String(a)
    var n = ""
    n = String(a)
    let hImage = UIImage.init(named: n)
    HistoricalImage.image = hImage

 //Below is the part that matters above was to just give context

    let path = NSTemporaryDirectory()+"1.txt"

    let readFile = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    HistoricalLabel.text = readFile

}
```

}

Here is an image of the view:
[image]

Here is an image of the view after execution:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check you string with print() statement and make sure its not empty

Comment: Oh shoot you're right it is empty. Do you have any suggestions for handling this?

Comment: I think [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file) you can find solution

Comment: Where is your text file?

Comment: @Desdenova in the bar to the right in a folder with other text files

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043864/objective-c-reading-text-files

Answer (score 1):

Label is not gone but you are setting empty string i think. You got empty string while reading text file.

Comment: Why though? My text file contains text. Is there something wrong with grabbing the text?

Comment: path = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(folder)
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName + "." + fileType)

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file

Comment: https://peterwitham.com/swift/intermediate/basic-file-reading-and-writing-in-ios-8/

Comment: let fileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename", ofType: "txt")!
let text : String
do
{
    text = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation)
}
catch
{
    text = ""
}

Comment: Can you put screenshot where is your file located?

Comment: Make sure your text file is added in your project target.